# Change Ruby version path for compass

Tags: ruby, sass, osx-yosemite, compass

I updated to Yosemite earlier this week and am having trouble running compass.

When trying to run `compass watch` it gives me this error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/compass: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin
/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Compass and SASS are both updated to the latest versions.

RVM is installed and working but I'm unsure of how to use it with my existing projects so the path to sass and compass in the correct place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the version of Ruby you are using is what is required by Compass Watch. Yosemite ships with version Ruby 2.0.0 as default. If you need to install a newer / older version I would suggest using RVM (http://rvm.io)

Install RVM:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Check Ruby version

```
ruby -v
```

Did you specify a Ruby version in your Gemfile?

Comment: Thanks! I am a noob to Ruby and didn't know about the Gemfile, specifying the Ruby version in there fixed it.